# Customized result file CI- JMeter

Tags: jmeter

After the test plan execution, I need the result file with only 5 fields value i.e. Date,Time, Response message,Response header and Error count in a text file format.Is this possible?I'm doing this for continuous Integration purpose as I need to publish result in the required format.

Comment: Editing this question since I have made some progress using Flexible File Writer Plug-in.I am able to write some of the fields and trying to write variables as well.But one challenge I see here is that Flexible file writer is used in GUI mode but for CI purpose I will need to run JMeter in non GUI mode.How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control what is stored in .jtl result file using relevant JMeter Properties.

For instance, to save timestamp, Message and headers you can add the following lines to *user.properties* file (which sits in /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
```

See

- [JavaDoc on SimpleDateFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn how you can set timestamp format
- JMeter Properties which contain `saveservice` in their names in *jmeter.properties* file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation to see available properties and their default values
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for extra information on various JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them

Comment: These lines,when added to user.properties file, generate the timestamp in jmeter.log file.But I am using Flexible file writer to write my results in a text file which I need to email over SMTP after generation.I need the timestamp,Response message and Response time in this text file instead of log file.Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not very fond of JMeter Plugins stuff, I consider them useless as any of them can be substituted either via existing JMeter functionality or light scripting. In case of Flexible File Writer, it can save `sampleLabel`. If you put [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function in the sampler "Name" input and tell FFW to store "sampleLabel" it should do the trick for you. See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)  post series for more information on __time() and other JMeter functions